# background image horizontal scroll

Tags: css

I am customizing the look and feel of the SharePoint home page where I have an image on the top of the page with size 1920 x 200 px and on the below is the navigation which needs to have a background color. When I provided the background color property, it doesn't cover the whole page. So I added the background image with the same length as the image on the top of the page but it still doesn't cover the whole page with CSS below(Click on the image).Looks like image is cropped when I have a horizontal scroll bar. What am I doing wrong?

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCI25.png)

```css
#Globalnav {
    background-image: url("http://sharepointdemo/sites/demo/Style Library/Images/yellow_background.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height:30px;
    
}
```

Comment: It would be better to understand your question if you provide any working url for example. As far as I understand, you should check #Globalnav parent's margin and padding.

Comment: Wait can you explain us again what you are trying to achieve here ? I'm kinda confused.

Comment: Can you post the entire code? So we can have a look